# Div height = 100% while scrolling

Tags: html, scroll, height

I've been looking around and all the answers for 100% div height basically says you have to specify it in html,body, etc., and this works great until you have to scroll down to see more content on the page. Here is an example of the issue:
http://503rephotography.com/_temp/test2.html - looks ok until you scroll down to see more content. Pardon the lack of style here, it's not pretty, just trying to grasp the concept before moving ahead.

Here's an example where it works fine since there is very little content on the page:
http://503rephotography.com/_temp/test3.html

Does anyone know how I can make the div on the left keep going to the end of the page regardless of how much content is on there? Any input is much appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could specify fixed positioning (position:fixed;) and a higher z-index than everything else (z-index:1000;) on that nav.

Comment: This totally did what I was looking for, THANKS!!! So simple, I just haven't gotten up to speed on CSS yet. Thanks a million, you rule!